# Why can't I see my shared folder from windows 10 anymore?

Tags: virtualbox, windows, shared-folders

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS via Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1 on Windows 10.  I have one shared folder auto-mounted with full access,  This has been working for a long time now, but I can't see the folder this morning in Ubuntu. I haven't changed anything except for updating Ubuntu.

Comment: Depending on how much of an update it was (and the number of updates to VirtualBox the VM has gone through), you may need to use the "Guest Additions" to install updated drivers 

Comment: I tried running "sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils" per a previous post's answer, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you see anything under `/media`?

Comment: Actually, the sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils did work, but I had to restart my Ubuntu vm to see that.

Comment: Cool. So you're all good now?